# How is it thermodynamically possible to obtain energy from a piece of coal?

Tags: thermodynamics, free-energy

If we put a piece of coal in open air we don't get any energy of it. But if we put fire to it in open air we get energy. Explain it with help of Gibbs free energy.

Answer (score 2):

Coal in open air can and does sponstaneously combust.

See for example [Spontaneous Heating and Fire in Coal Mines](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877705813012289) and [Coal’s Spontaneous Combustion Problem](http://daily.sightline.org/2012/04/11/coals-spontaneous-combustion-problem/).

At low temperature the change in Gibbs free energy of coal oxidation is still strongly negative, just like at high temperature.

But at low temperature, the reaction rate is low.

Still, if the rate at which heat is dissipated is less that the rate at which heat is produced, temperature increases and the reaction rate increases until there is appreciable combusiton.

Answer (score 1):

One of the features of a solid is that there is very little movement of the molecules. This prevents most reactions from occurring due to the lack of energy to achieve the activation energy for the reaction. If the coal is already burning, then some surface molecules could absorb the energy (of the fire) to break away from the solid so the reaction with the oxygen is far easier.